# Division using Counts in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Basic question, but I am trying to do division with sql statements to return a single value.

I want to get the number of rows with a value less than 40 in the 'random_num' column divided by the total number of rows but I keep getting an error.  Anyone mind pointing out how I would do this/

select count(*) / ( select count (*) from ABC)
FROM ABC
WHERE random_num < 40

```
 create table abc (continent varchar2(30), country varchar2(30), random_num number,   yr number)
 insert into abc values ('asia', 'india', 50, 2005)
 insert into abc values ('asia', 'japan', 100, 2006)
 insert into abc values('asia', 'korea', 35, 2007)
 insert into abc values ('asia', 'china', 200, 2008)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way would be to use a `CASE` to count the rows with a value < 40;

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN random_num < 40 THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*) ratio FROM abc
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cea25/1)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT (SELECT sum(random_num) FROM abc WHERE random_num < 40)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc) as division`